# Ubuntu 15.04 & Windows 8.1 dual boot boots directly into Windows - how can I get the GRUB menu to show up?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Background: Windows 8.1 was installed in BIOS mode on a RAID 1.  I removed RAID and went to AHCI so I have 2 individual drives.  Removed all partitions on drive 1. Drive 0, Windows 8.1 boots OK.  Installed Ubuntu from DVD in BIOS mode and installed, made `/`, `/home` & swap partitions, installed Ubuntu.

Problem: When I boot up the PC, it boots directly into Windows 8.1.  Going into BIOS/UEFI menu I can select boot order of disk 0 (windows) or cd/dvd (no disk 1 option) though in a manual boot options I can select drive 1 (ubuntu).  If I select drive 1, it boots Ubuntu and I see the Ubuntu boot menu where I can select to boot Ubuntu or Windows 8.1 as part of my boot options.  Selecting Ubuntu boots into Ubuntu OK, selecting Windows boots into Windows OK.

Question: How to fix/configure this system so it will offer an OS Boot Option when I do a normal boot?

Comment: Did you set your bios to boot in secure mode? When I ran two drives, Ubuntu and Windows, I had to press the "F12" key to get the Bios boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on Windows and adding Ubuntu to the menu (in **Linux > Grub2** I selected *drive 1 linux root partition*).  Now it boots Windows and gives a menu to select Windows or Ubuntu and it works great.