# Dual booting windows 8.1 and ubuntu, windows automatically loads

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

So I recently attempted dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 on a HP Pavilion G6. So far I've gotten everything working except whenever I turn on or restart my computer, it loads straight into windows. Currently the only way to get into Ubuntu is to get into my UEFI Firmware settings, entering Boot Device options and selecting Ubuntu. I've been researching for the past half an hour and I've tried the following:

- Disabling fast boot
- Running a boot repair in Ubuntu (Recommended settings)
- Typing in cmd in windows

  ```
  bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
  ```

Nothing I do seems to work and windows just keeps on loading up.

Comment: I also got this link when performing a boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12078211/

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Many HPs have buggy firmware that produces the problem you relate. If the machine is new enough, I recommend you return it for a refund and buy something else. If it's beyond the return period, see [this question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464021/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-before-windows-8-1) for some workarounds. (There are many other questions/answers here about this problem, but that's the one I found first.)

Comment: Another link with similar suggestions. Most with HP copy shimx64.efi inot /EFI/Boot and rename to bootx64.efi. They may have to add a UEFI boot entry if one does not exist or reboot several times to get UEFI to see it. Others have used Rod Smith's rEFInd with good success. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: I had the same issue:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/659393/ubuntu-15-04-windows-8-1-dual-boot-boot-directly-into-windows?noredirect=1#comment948751_659393

I ended up using EasyBCD.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing GRUB, or enabling it, if it's installed:

1. Boot the machine using a Live CD.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Find out the name of the internal disk by using fdisk to look up the device's size.
   For example:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
4. Install GRUB boot loader onto the proper disk (the example below assumes it is `/dev/sda`):

   ```
   grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda
   ```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader/126586#126586)

NOTE: you might need to install GRUB... A good guide is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/341392/ubuntu-11-04-64-bit-wont-boot-forgot-to-install-grub-2-manual-grub-install/341422#341422) answer.

Comment: I tried this but when I run the second command with my interal disk, it says grub-install: error: cannot open directory '/boot/grub/i386-pc': No such file or directory.

Comment: @Jakegeyer27 Are using 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: yes I am using 64bit

Comment: @Jakegeyer27 See edit at the end of my answer